# Using .readlines() and struggling to access the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I am struggling to access the list created by using .readlines() when opening the text file. The file opens correctly, but I am not sure how I can access the list in the function 'display_clues()'.

```
def clues_open():
    try:
        cluesfile = open("clues.txt","r")
        clue_list = cluesfile.readlines()
    except:
        print("Oops! Something went wrong (Error Code 3)")
        exit()

def display_clues():
    clues_yes_or_no = input("Would you like to see the clues? Enter Y/N: ")
    clues_yes_or_no = clues_yes_or_no.lower()
    if clues_yes_or_no == "y":
        clues_open()
        print(clue_list)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
display_clues()
File "N:\Personal Projecs\game\game.py", line 35, in      display_clues
print(clue_list)
NameError: name 'clue_list' is not defined
```

Thanks!

Comment: you got any error or something??? or it just printed list

Comment: I have edited your code, it will work now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def clues_open():
    try:
        cluesfile = open("clues.txt","r")
        clue_list = cluesfile.readlines()
        #print clue_list   #either print the list here
        return clue_list   # or return the list
    except:
        print("Oops! Something went wrong (Error Code 3)")
        exit()
def display_clues():
    clues_yes_or_no = raw_input("Would you like to see the clues? Enter Y/N: ")
    clues_yes_or_no = clues_yes_or_no.lower()
    if clues_yes_or_no == "y":
        clue_list = clues_open()  # catch list here
        print clue_list


display_clues()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the list from `clues_open()` to `display_clues()`:

```
def clues_open():
   with open("clues.txt","r") as cluesfile:
       return cluesfile.readlines()

def display_clues(): 
    clues_yes_or_no = input("Would you like to see the clues? Enter Y/N: ")    
    if clues_yes_or_no.lower() == "y": 
        clues_list = clues_open()
        print(clue_list)
```

As a side note: I removed your worse than useless except block. Never use a bare except clause, never assume what actually went wrong, and only catch exception you can really handle.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, the text file contains data and it currently prints as 'none', there isn't a 'none' in the text file, how do I get the text file to print the data held in it?

Comment: @user3731036 : with the exact same code I get the expected behaviour (=> it does print the list - which is probably not what you really want but that's not the question) here using python 2.7